# Observing change in value of member variable

Tags: c++

I want to get notification on modification of some class member-variable(may be primitive or user-defined).

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Little more clarification to my question:

I have scenario something like

I have existing menu and menu-items. Now I am putting all these menu-items on toolbar. Since when these menu-items was inside menu-item I get event ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI where I call a function and update menu-items states.

But now for toolbar I have to put function for checking state every time, variables(which are many in number and also gets modified at many state, for which I have no control).

Can anyone suggest me some good alternative, without changing the existing code, since it's very fragile.

Is there any way we get some variable change notification from language/compiler, such as the way the Watch variable works in visual studio debugger.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Is the for debugging? Logging during normal use? Is this a permanent feature you need added to your software? Your question is very, very vague.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention ***notifications***(*which indicates receiving intimations asynchronously*), What you need is an:
[**Observer design pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 3):

You can make the variable `private` and access it through `getter/setter` methods which are publicly available. Put the print or your custom asserts inside those getter/setters.
e.g.:

```
class A {
private:
  int x;
public:
  int getx () const { /* your code */ ; return x; }
  void setx (const int i) { /* your code */; x = i; }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't ***notify*** of any change, this is explicitly checking status(*How will you know when to call the getters?*) or have I mistaken?

Comment: @Als, yes. getter/setters are very common practice which can be implemented with much ease. One has to just write the custom code inside it when needed. No overkill, but simple debugging. Here the notification will be in user defined way, i.e. prints, asserts, or anything which user chooses.

Comment: The Q is ***How does this notify of any change in the variable?*** OP specifically said **Notification**.In short I don't think this provides the functionality that OP asks for.It provides a means to check values of certain class member but not to get any notifications.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#C.2B.2B).