# Handle a value being changed in a c++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, detection

I have a struct that describes how the system should be initialised. I then have a method that returns a reference to said struct so that the user of the final system can change certain options after initialisation. I wish to detect when a value is changed and tell the component parts of the system to check for options they depend on to see if they've been changed and update themselves accordingly.

I believe such a thing is possible by overloading an operator or something similar. I don't really mind about overhead and what the detection & updating code looks like, I just want the syntax for changing an option to look clean, and for the user to not have to call a `updateOptions()` function after changes or anything.

Firstly, is this even possible? Secondly, if it is, how would I go about it?

Comment: Overloading an operator has nothing to do with this (at least, not fundamentally), and detecting _when_ something happens depends entirely on how you're passing events around your system and handling them. I can't tell you how to do it when I don't know your system. But, is it possible? Sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Observing change in value of member variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880253/observing-change-in-value-of-member-variable)

Comment: Look at operator==, the observer pattern, boost signalling for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume your struct is named `Fun`

**Solution 1: Add getter, setter and notify**

I would write a getter and a setter for each properties of the said struct. It would look like this:

```
struct Fun {
    Fun(System& sys): system{sys} {}

    void setGun(int g) {
        gun = g;
        notify();
    }

    int getGun() {
        return gun;
    }

    void notify() {
            system.updated();
    }

private:
    System& system;
    int gun;
};
```

Of course, the reference can be a pointer and of course, you will have to separate the struct to a header and cpp file.

**Solution 2: write a get and set for the struct Fun**

The advantage of this solution is that it might be the fastest, and of course the cleanest one.

```
struct System {
    void setFun(Fun f) {
        if (f != fun) {
            // update only if different
            updated();
        }
        // it may be faster if Fun allocates resources
        fun = move(f);
    }

    // do not return by reference
    Fun getFun() const {
        return fun;
    }

private:
    Fun fun;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, changing a single item can cause the entire setting to become invalid but changing 2 or 3 can be a valid setting.

If this is the case, you can should create a `getter/setter` function pair.  The `getter` function will return a copy of the struct and the `setter` function will effectively be an updateSetting function.

This has very little overhead and is more robust than having a getter/seeter per item.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would emit an appropriate [boost signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/signals.html) in the setter function for each option, and have subscribers sign up for these signals. I would use a class instead of a struct for clarity, because you'll want everything to be private except for exposed signals, setters and getters.

Comment: I don't see how that gives you "clarity".

Comment: Everything is public in a struct by default, so I would find it unclear if it's used in a case like this with a lot of private logic.

Comment: So what? Make that logic private. Nice suggestion of boost signal though.

Comment: I was specifically trying to avoid having to use setters. I would prefer syntax like ` options.windowTitle = "My Window!"; ` Sorry if I did not make this clear.

Comment: @Luke: I don't see it. "a struct" no such thing as compared to "a class". Both keywords `struct` and `class` define "a class". Literally the same entity. No idea why people fuss over the two!! The different default access specifiers don't give anything more "clarity" in my view. *shrug*

Comment: @Luke There wasn't any claim for `boost` ([No one expects the spanish inqusition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WJXHY2OXGE))

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have a struct that describes how the system should be initialised. I then have a method that returns a reference to said struct so that the user of the final system can change certain options after initialisation."*

That's probably the wrong approach. Better use getter/setter functions for the single properties, such your class can control, how to react on property changes.

Another way would be to let the client retrieve a `const` reference to your interned properties `struct` member variable, make a copy of it, change that one and pass it back with a setter (update) function. This would make the process much clearer for the client, than having to call an extra `update()` function.